# Return city ID and name JSON MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have function in MVC controller that get cities by country ID
And I have java script function that calling this method in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetcitiesBycountry(string selectedValue)
{
List<string> cityList = new List<string>();
if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue.Length > 0)
{
using (InstructoroEntities dataContext = new InstructoroEntities())
{
int ID = int.Parse(selectedValue);
List<string> getcities = dataContext.Cities.Where(query => query.CountryID 
==ID).Select(q => q.CityName).ToList();
cityList = getcities;
}
}
return Json(new { CityList = cityList });
}


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#CountryID").change(function () {
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("GetcitiesBycountry", "Registration")',
type: 'POST',
data: { "selectedValue": selectedValue },
dataType: 'json',
success: function (response) {
var items = "";
$.each(response.CityList, function (i, item) {
items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>";
});
$("#CityName").html(items);
},
error: function (error) {
}

});
});
</script>
```

Simply I want to get City ID and name instead of name only 
best regards.

Comment: Awful code formatting (indentation) did you proof-read it before posting?

Comment: So do you want `Select(q => new { q.CityName, q.CityId });`

Comment: I try this before but all problem how i render this in
  $.each(response.CityList, function (i, item) {
   items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>";
   });
    $("#CityName").html(items);

Comment: Then change your js to `items += "<option value=\"" + item.CityId + "\">" + item.CityName + "</option>";`

Comment: Thanks for your concern 
I want to know instead of loop $.each(response.CityList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change like following.

C#: Use

```
var getcities = dataContext.Cities.Where(query => query.CountryID ==ID)
.Select(q => new{q.CityName, q.CityID}).ToList(); 
    }
}   
return Json(getcities);
```

Instead of

```
List<string> getcities = dataContext.Cities.Where(query => query.CountryID 
==ID).Select(q => q.CityName).ToList();
cityList = getcities;
    }
}
return Json(new { CityList = cityList });
```

JQuery: Use

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    items += "<option value=\"" + item.CityID + "\">" + item.CityName + "</option>";
});
```

Instead of

```
$.each(response.CityList, function (i, item) {
    items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>";
});
```

Comment: thanks first
 and instead of thid  return Json(new { CityList = cityList });
?

Comment: Thanks for your concern @Azim I want to know instead of 
 return Json(new { CityList = cityList });
in controller (c#)
and 
the loop in JQuery
$.each(response.CityList, function (i, item) {}
so grateful

Comment: I've given more details.